# Copying the appstore button all/not in this ipad in buys

Tags: ios6

I would just like to replicate the appstore 2 buttons system between "all" and "not on this ipad" in the "buys" section, that displays 2 different table. is that custom or library basic?

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use SEGMENTED CONTROL and do it manually to look app store alike